# Python Docstring - two different types of arguments of a function

Tags: python, docstring

I tried to make my function-description look beautiful but it didn't work. The problem is that I have two types of returns: a list and a string. Then you hover on functions vscode shows the returns of the functions like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPyRV.png).
I found out that you can define one type of return using this example (-> str):

```
def function(x, y) -> str:
  string = "test"
  return string
```

But let's say I have tow diffrent return in my code:

```
def function(x, y):
  if x == 1:
    string = "test"
    return string
  else:
    list = [1, 2]
    return list
```

How to assign two different types of returns to that function? [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpHol.png) is another example

Comment: You probably don't want a function with return type `Union[str, list]` in the first place. (As an aside, docstrings are not involved here at all.)

Comment: As per comment above, the syntax is `Union[str, list]` but it is a bad idea to have a function that returns one of two unrelated types - that will complicate all the other code that has to call that function. Avoiding that will probably lead to a better design.

Comment: [In what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Comment: And as referenced -- these are type hints, which are a completely different thing than docstrings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your Python version, there are multiple ways this can be epxressed:

- Prior to 3.9:

  ```
  from typing import Union, List
  def foo() -> Union[str, List]: pass
  ```
- Since Python v. 3.9 you can also write:

  ```
   from typing import Union
   def foo() -> Union[str, list]: pass
  ```
- Since Python v. 3.10 you can also write:

  ```
   def foo() -> str | list: pass
  ```

Answer (score 1):

```
from typing import Union, List

def function(x, y) -> Union[str, List[int]]:
  if x == 1:
    return "test"
  return [1, 2]
```